# How to play video in android after Button click

Tags: android, android-videoview

I am trying to design simple code in android for play video after a button click but i am getting unknown problem.  My present project files below. I am clueless right now. Please point out a thing or solve this problem. Thanks again!

```
public class VideoActivity extends Activity {
    VideoView video;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        play = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);


        play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(View v) {

               VideoView myVideoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.myvideoview);
               myVideoView.setVideoPath("/mnt/usb_storage/vivek.3gp");
               myVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
               myVideoView.requestFocus();
               myVideoView.start();
           }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: **And whats the problem**?

Comment: this code not give any error but after run in tablet nothing happened even when i run this code without button this work properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                    try 
                    {
                        videoView.setVideoPath(videoPath);
                        videoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(Applicaion Context or YourActivity.this));
                        videoView.start();

                    }
                    catch (Exception e) 
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        System.out.println("Error in btnInfo Click -->"+e.toString());
                    }
                }
            });
            //BtnPlay
```